# Mysql Query - join, subquery, if exists

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:  `Inventory`, `style`, `sizes`, `style_sizes`

`Inventory` contains columns  `user_id`, `style`, `size` etc.
`Style` contains columns: `style_id`, `style` (the name of the style) etc.
`Sizes` contains columns: `size_id`, `size`, etc. (sm, md, lg, etc)
`style_sizes` contains columns: `style_size_id`, `style_id`, `size_id` (this is to list the sizes available for selected style)

What I need is to list all inventory for "user_id = x" and "style = y" (not style_id) where the user has the `size` and to order by `size_id`.

Currently, it is showing for all sizes that are available for that style even if the user does not have any.

Here is query so far:

```
SELECT i.*, st.*, ss.* 
            FROM inventory as i
            JOIN style as st
            ON i.style = st.style
            JOIN style_sizes as ss
            ON st.style_id = ss.style_id
            WHERE i.user_id = $user_id AND i.style = :style
```

I am close but I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You should generally use the ID as the foreign key, not the name.

Comment: Yes.  But the way the variables are called I needed to use style not style_id.

Comment: I was talking about the schema. You can still use `style` in the `WHERE` clause, but joins should use IDs.

Comment: The way the variables play out I couldn't in this case.  table inventory doesn't have a i.style_id to join to st.style_id.  It only has i.style.  Normally, I absolutely would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `size_id` in the join so you only get the sizes for that user.

```
SELECT i.*, st.*, ss.* 
FROM inventory as i
JOIN style as st
    ON i.style = st.style
JOIN style_sizes as ss
    ON st.style_id = ss.style_id AND i.size_id = ss.size_id
WHERE i.user_id = :user_id AND i.style = :style
```

Comment: There was no i.size_id. so I joined sizes and changed i.size_id = ss.size_id to si.size_id.  Thanks so much.  All I needed was the "AND".

Comment: SELECT i.*, st.*, ss.* 
FROM inventory as i
JOIN style as st
    ON i.style = st.style
  JOIN sizes as si
  ON i.size = si.size
JOIN style_sizes as ss
    ON st.style_id = ss.style_id AND si.size_id = ss.size_id
WHERE i.user_id = $user_id AND i.style = :style

Comment: It would be easier if you posted the full schema, I had to guess what the foreign key would be. What is the `si` table?